# Notepad++ Regex [^a-z] not returning expected matches

Tags: notepad++

I am using the regular expression below in Notepad++ to find lines containing words in Upper case (and punctuation marks).

```
^[^a-z]*$
```

It is not returning any matches. Why?

(Specific line to be matched : "INSTANTANEOUS PERSONAL MAGNETISM, AVAILABLE HERE!")

Comment: The Regex worked when "Match case" was selected in the Find Dialog Box.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is missing a better text example with some lines. Your regular expression seems to be not clean code and does not work with text and numbers uniquely (as I expected).

Therefore I recommend the following procedure:

1. Open your file in Notepad++
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>
3. *Find What:* `\b[A-Z][A-Z]+\b`
4. Check *Bookmark line* and options as shown in the screenshot.

Please note, you have a bunch of options to process these lines from the main menu in a second step e.g. **Search > Bookmark > Copy Bookmarked lines**

[image]